# Shiny and CSV files

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am very new to programming and have been watching videos on how to build Shiny Apps via R Studio.

One thing I am struggling to find is simple code that I can use that asks Shiny to select a CSV file which is sitting on my desktop.

Can this be achieved or do I need to load the dataset into R Studio first?

I am unsure if I am confusing myself and should just be using the read/fileInput function instead

All help guides show this code:

```
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv")
```

So do I just replace the "text/csv" with my own path?

I am very confused with conflicting info and hope that someone can break this down for me in layman's terms

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should help: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

Comment: managed to get it working... thank you very much for your help! Do I just upload the file and I should be able to access it via R Studio?

Comment: Glad to hear, good job! Within the shinyapp you should be able to use it, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and feed back.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
#ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My shiny app"), sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("This app shows how a user can upload a csv file. Then, plot the data.
          Any file can be uploaded but analysis is only available
          if the data is in same format as the sample file, downloadable below
          "),
  a("Data to be plotted", href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3q2eayogbe0bgl/shiny_data.csv?dl=0"),
  tags$hr(),
  fileInput("file","Upload the file"), 
  h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = TRUE),
  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
  br(),
  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
),
mainPanel(
  uiOutput("tb"),
  plotOutput("line")             
)
)
)

#server.R
server <- function(input,output){
data <- reactive({


file1 <- input$file
if(is.null(file1)){return()} 

read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)})

output$filedf <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
input$file
}) 

output$sum <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
summary(data())
})

output$table <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
data()
})

output$line <- renderPlot({
if (is.null(data())) { return() }
print(ggplot(data(), aes(x=date, y=aa)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~station)) })

output$tb <- renderUI({if(is.null(data()))
h5()               
else
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

[image]